# Excel ETA calculator. With a twist

Tags: performance, excel, time, distance

Using Excel, I'm trying to calculate an estimated time of arrival(ETA) calculated from a departure date and time field and a distance field. The speed is the tough part because it varies depending on the time of day.

For now, let us assume that there are only two speed possibilities depending on the hour of the day. Between 8am and 7pm speed equals 16. Between 7pm and 8am speed equals 8. The actual numbers may be quite different so don't assume half speed at night.

I want to drop in a date and time and have the formula calculate ETA utilizing the distance and the appropriate speeds based on the time of day.

e.g. A 500 mile trip starting on Jan 1 at 6pm would result in 1Hr @16, 13Hr @8, 11Hr @16, 13Hr @8, 6.25Hr @16. A total of 44.25 hours arriving on Jan 3 at 2:15pm

Date plus 44.25 hour is stupid simple but, calculating the hours based on the start time and the speed possible during certain hours has eluded me.

[EDIT]
Wow, you put a lot of work into that and I really appreciate the effort. But, it doesn't do what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to take starting date and time, along with distance to destination, as input. Then it must calculate the ETA using the varying speeds during the day. Averages won't do at all. There is a precise ETA for each trip and the time to travel a fixed distance will vary significantly depending on the start time.

Comment: You should rephrase your question. You don't want to drop in a date/time, you want to drop in a date/time and distance (3 paramaters, not 2). That's correct, right?

Comment: never mind, please see my answer below, I devleoped a method for doing what you need. If it works, please accept as an answer :)

Comment: you should have a look at the file i made (download it [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?9g6avpfxvn4pq15)) because it doesn't average but really count the whole value (and you can choose more widely hour ranges)

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while, but I made the function you need. The date needs to be formatted like "2011/01/01 18:00" (make sure that the cell type of the date you are reading and the function result cell is of type date). You can easily change the value of speed 1 and 2 in the code to match your needs.

```vb
Function ETA(ByVal myTime As Date, _
             ByVal distance As Double) As Date

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim startTime As Date
Dim minCounter As Double
Dim result As Date
Dim milesTraveled As Double

' add the first hour
myTime = DateAdd("h", 1, myTime)
While distance - milesTraveled >= 16
    If Hour(myTime) >= 8 And Hour(myTime) <= 19 Then
        milesTraveled = milesTraveled + 16
    Else
        milesTraveled = milesTraveled + 8
    End If
    ' increment the time by 1 hour
    myTime = DateAdd("h", 1, myTime)
Wend

' check if any miles left to go (less than 1 hour's worth)
' and calculate minutes based on speed value
If distance - milesTraveled <> 0 Then
    ' ugly error checking to make sure that this isn't the
    ' last hour in the 8 speed period to avoid erroneous
    ' results. You can fix this up to be cleaner.
    If distance - milesTravel >= 8 And Hour(myTime) = 7 Then
        myTime = DateAdd("h", 1, myTime)
        milesTraveled = milesTraveled + 8
        minCounter = ((distance - milesTraveled) / 16) * 60
    Else
        If Hour(myTime) >= 8 And Hour(myTime) <= 19 Then
            minCounter = ((distance - milesTraveled) / 16) * 60
        Else
            minCounter = ((distance - milesTraveled) / 8) * 60
        End If
    End If
End If

' Add left over minutes
result = DateAdd("n", minCounter, myTime)
ETA = result
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

I tested the code and passed it =ETA(cellwithdate, 500) and 2011/01/01 18:00 as the value in the cellwithdate and the result is correctly returned as 2011/01/03 14:15.

How it works:
I check to make sure that there is a full hour's worth of miles to travel (distance - miles traveled is 16 or more). Then for that hour, I check if it's in range 1 (8am and 7pm), if it is, then miles traveled is 16, if not, it's 8. Then I add 1 to the hour. When there is less than 1 hours worth of travel left, I calculate the minutes. You can work on this and make the code cleaner so that it's faster/error checking is added, but this function should show you one way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [User-Defined Function](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Writing_Your_First_VBA_Function_in_Excel/631.html) and adapt the following code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function ETA(dStart As Date, dEnd As Date) As Date
Dim lAvg As Double
Dim iNumDays As Integer, iHours As Integer
Dim lSpeed As Long
Dim dTemp As Date
Dim dFinal As Date

'Get average speed for each full day
lAvg = Application.Average(Range("Speed"))
'Get the number of full days
iNumDays = CInt(dEnd - dStart)
'Add the days
dFinal = iNumDays * lAvg

'Parse every hour from start to midnight
'if end date is midnight, need to correct the loop
If Hour(dEnd) = 0 Then
    iHours = 24
Else
    iHours = Hour(dEnd)
End If
dTemp = dStart
Do While TimeValue(dTemp) <> "00:00:00" And Hour(dTemp) < iHours
    lSpeed = Application.VLookup(Format(dTemp, "hh:mm AM/PM"), Range("TimeSpeed"), 2, False)
    dFinal = DateAdd("h", lSpeed, dFinal)
    'parse another hour
    dTemp = DateAdd("h", 1, dTemp)
Loop

'Do not count the hour twice
'  Check if first date and last date aren't on the same day
'  or start time is midnight
If Day(dStart) <> Day(dEnd) Or TimeValue(dStart) = "00:00:00" Then
    'Parse every hour from midnight to end
    dTemp = dEnd
    Do While TimeValue(dTemp) <> "00:00:00" And Hour(dTemp) > Hour(dStart)
        lSpeed = Application.VLookup(Format(dTemp, "hh:mm AM/PM"), Range("TimeSpeed"), 2, False)
        dFinal = DateAdd("h", lSpeed, dFinal)
        'parse another hour (step backward)
        dTemp = DateAdd("h", -1, dTemp)
    Loop
End If

ETA = dFinal
End Function
```

you will have to use [named ranges](http://www.contextures.com/xlnames01.html):

- `TimeSpeed` is range: `A2:B25`
- `Speed` is range `B2:B25`

i uploaded a sample file [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?9g6avpfxvn4pq15)

if anybody has a better idea to cope with this issue, you are welcome!

Comment: Wow, you put a lot of work into that and I really appreciate the effort. But, it doesn't do what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to take starting date and time, along with distance to destination, as input. Then it must calculate the ETA using the varying speeds during the day. Averages won't do at all. There is a precise ETA for each trip and the time to travel a fixed distance will vary significantly depending on the start time.

Comment: Added the "<!-- language: lang-vb -->" tag  so that your code is formated properly. :)

Comment: Yeah, if you add it to the line above the code, it will change the format. I think it defaults to whatever tags the question has, but sometimes you have to do it manually. :) Sometimes it's a pain and you need to add it to the line above your code, then reselect the code using {} for it to take effect.